# Connecting to SQL server using PYODBC

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am able to connect to the SQL server 2008 R2 using Python in jupyter notebook, but when I select top 10 rows from a table, the results are not rendered on the screen. I do not get any error. I need to know how can I select the data from a table in SQL and the result gets displayed on the screen. Below is code that I used:

```
import pyodbc 
con = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}',server = 'ServerName', database = 'DBname')


cursor.execute("select top 10 accountid from Table")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. What happens if you try `cursor.execute("select COUNT(*) AS N from Table")` ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you missed creating the actual cursor:

```
import pyodbc 


con = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}',server = 'ServerName', database = 'DBname')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("select top 10 accountid from Table")
rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Good luck!